# PowerShell FileSystemWatcher Not Working With Mapped Azure File Share

Tags: azure, powershell, filesystemwatcher, azure-files

I'm trying to monitor files appearing in an azure file share using the FileSystemWatcher in PowerShell. The script works correctly when looking at folders on the machine, but when I point it to look at a mapped rive that has been mapped to azure File share it reports "The directory name is invalid.

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The directory name  is invalid."

The mapped drive appears in explorer and can be accessed.  Can FileSystemWatcher access azure resources?

Comment: By FileSystemWatcher are you referring to this https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Answer (score 0):

FileSystemWatcher works well with monitoring mounted Azure File Shares as well.

You would just have to [mount the file share correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#mount-the-azure-file-share) and assign it a Drive letter. For example, I have an active file share mounted as Drive **Z:\** on my machine.

Once mapped, set the `folder` and `filter` variables:

```
$folder = 'Z:\' # Or the drive letter you have the share mounted onto
$filter = '*.*'

# Create an instance of the FileSystemWatcher class
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}
```

The rest of the [script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b) can be executed as is. Here is how it would look:

[image: FileSystemWatcher]